# Why is my guide in Terraria not respawning?

Tags: terraria

I spawned in the WoF and then when I died to it, my guide didn't respawn. I waited like 20 in-game days, still didn't respawn. I then waited a real life day then came back and he still didn't respawn. All of my other NPCs are spawning, and I already checked and all of my houses are valid.

Answer (score 0):

NPCs only spawn back in if there is a spare house. I would recommend checking that, but I otherwise don't know what to tell you.